# separate each value with comma from multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<select multiple='multiple'` and I need to show the selected value in a div or some other part of the page.

I did this but the string is all smushed together. How can I separate each value with a comma?

I made a [**live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2C523/12/) with what I have so far.

Or if you prefer, here is the code:

**html:**

```
<select multiple='multiple' id="selMulti">
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
     <option value="4">Option 4</option>    
</select>
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go!" />
<div style="margin-top: 10px;" id="result"></div>
```

**js:**

```
$("#go").click(function(){
     var selMulti = $("#selMulti option:selected").text();
     $("#result").text(selMulti);
});
```

If you select the option 1 and 2, the result will be:

`Option 1Option 2`

What I need is:

`Option 1, Option 2`

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for having already asked this so I didn't have to ask and wait for an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to map the elements to an array and then join them:

```
$("#go").click(function(){
     var selMulti = $.map($("#selMulti option:selected"), function (el, i) {
         return $(el).text();
     });
     $("#result").text(selMulti.join(", "));
});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AcfUz/**

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: Pretty freakin great soloution! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#go").click(function(){
     var textToAppend = "";
     var selMulti = $("#selMulti option:selected").each(function(){
           textToAppend += (textToAppend == "") ? "" : ",";
           textToAppend += $(this).text();           
     });
     $("#result").html(textToAppend);
});
```

Comment: Need to add ` + ','` in the append call

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a comma-separated result.

Comment: Now your solution will append a comma to the end of the string, e.g. `Option 2,Option 3,`

Comment: Now should work as expeced, but its's more complicated then Andy E solution.

Answer (score 2):

One line style:

```
 $("#selMulti option:selected").map(function(){return this.text}).get().join(', ');
```

Output:

```
"Option 1, Option 2"
```